# Is it possible to return more than one value from jQuery call?

Tags: php, jquery

I have this code: messages.php

```
if (count($row) > 0)
{
    foreach ($row as $r)
    {
        //some code setting variables
        if ($opened_once >= 1)
        {   

        }
        else
        {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo '<td><a class="red_link" href="'.ADDRESS.'view_message.php?id='.$r['id'].'" id= "subject_id" ><span id = "subject">'.$r['subject'].'</span></a></td>';
            echo '<td id = "unique_code1">'.$uniqueCode1.'<span class="pink_text" id = "unique_code2">'.$uniqueCode2.'</span><span id = "unique_code3">'.$uniqueCode3.'</span></td>';
            echo "</tr>";
        }
    }
```

I need to update `$r['id']`, `$r['subject']`, `$uniqueCode1`, `$uniqueCode2`, `$uniqueCode`

My jQuery code:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        refresh();
    });

    function refresh()
    {      
        $.post('getMessageDetails.php', function (json) {
        $("#subject").html(json.subject);
        $("#subject_id").html(json.subject_id);
        $("#unique_code1").html(json.unique_code1);
        $("#unique_code2").html(json.unique_code2);
        $("#unique_code3").html(json.unique_code3);
        });   

        window.setTimeout(refresh,30000);
    }   
</script>
```

Then I have newMessageCnt.php

```
<?php
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
include('header_application.php');

$limit = 15;
if(!isset($_GET['page']))
   $page = 1;
else
   $page = $_GET['page'];

$from = (($page * $limit) - $limit);
$row = $obj_clean->getMessages($_SESSION['user_id'], $from, $limit);

if (count($row) > 0)
{
    foreach ($row as $r)
    {
        $codeLength = strlen($r['unique_code']);
        $codeLength = strlen($r['unique_code']);
        $firstPartLength = $codeLength - 5;
        $uniqueCode3 = substr($r['unique_code'], -2);
        $uniqueCode2 = substr($r['unique_code'], -5, 3);
        $uniqueCode1 = substr($r['unique_code'], 0, $firstPartLength);

        $message_id = $r['id'];
        $subject = $obj_clean->getMessageDetails($message_id);
        $opened_once = $obj_clean->getOpenedOnce($message_id);
        if ($opened_once >= 1)
        {   
            $array['subject'] = $r['subject'];
            $array['subject_id'] = $r['id'];
            $array['unique_code1'] = $uniqueCode1;
            $array['unique_code2'] = $uniqueCode2;
            $array['unique_code3'] = $uniqueCode3;
        }
    }    
}
echo json_encode($array);
exit();
```

?>
    ?>

I call this .php somewhere else as well where I just want the value of `echo $obj_clean->getUnopenedMessagesCount($_SESSION['user_id']);`

But from my messages.php I want

```
echo '<td><a class="blue_link" href="'.ADDRESS.'view_message.php?id='.$r['id'].'">'.$r['subject'].'</a></td>';
echo '<td>'.$uniqueCode1.'<span class="pink_text">'.$uniqueCode2.'</span>'.$uniqueCode3.'</td>';
```

I'm not sure if I'm doing this right, some advice please?

Answer (score 3):

```
$.post('ajax_call.php', function (json) {
        $("#subject").html(json.subject);
        $("#unique_code").html(json.unique_code);
});
```

//ajax_call.php

```
<?php
$array['subject']='bla-bla';
$array['unique_code']='1231312';

header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
echo json_encode($array);
exit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Better would be to have your PHP return an object containing the values you want as properties.  This can be sent back to the browser using JSON.  Your client-side code see this as an object and can extract the properties and populate the HTML.  This separates your presentation (VIEW) from your data (MODEL).

EDIT: Exactly as @TROODON has answered.

Comment: just one last thing: json returns the subject and unique code but in my html tags i have the unique_code in 3 parts(with one tag id) and also the subject is a link with the message id and also with one tag id??. how will i handle this please? this is all very new to me.thank you for the help so far :)

Comment: Simply return the values from PHP that make their use as easy as possible in your JavaScript.  If you require data in 3 parts then return it in 3 parts.  Use your JavaScript to embed the returned values into the browser DOM.

Comment: must i then have a tag id for each of the parts? sorry i dont follow :(

Comment: Yes. Add whatever attributes that make it easiest to identify the HTML elements.

Comment: please see my changed/new code at the top..is this right then?

Comment: You need to follow the example code given by @TROODON more closely.  You must set the `content-type` header value towards the start of your PHP code and you must also return the content in JSON format using `json_encode()`.  Otherwise I think you are getting there.

Comment: oops i changed the .php again and moved the header part to the top and have the  echo json_encode($array); and exit();

the new code is at the top